# Не могу понять в чем проблема:

Tags: c++

> Напишите шаблонную функцию max5(), которая принимает в качестве
>   аргумента массив из пяти элементов типа T и возвращает наибольший элемент в
>   массиве. (Поскольку размер массива фиксирован, его можно жестко закодировать в
>   цикле, а не передавать в виде аргумента.) Протестируйте функцию в
>   программе с использованием массива из пяти значений int и массива из пяти значений double.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
const int arr_size = 5;
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
T max5(T arr[])
{
    T maxValue = arr[0];
    for(int i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
        if(arr[i]>maxValue)
        maxValue=arr[i];
    return maxValue;
}
int main()
{
    int arri=arr_size;
    for(int i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
    {
        cout << "[" << i + 1 << "]" << ": ";
        cin >> arri[i];     
    }
    double arrd=arr_size;
    for(double i=0; i<arr_size; i++) 
    {
        cout << "[" << i + 1 << "]" << ": ";
        cin >> arrd[i];     
    } 
    cout << " massiv iArr iz 5 zna4enij  tipa   INT : ";
    cout<< (arri);
    cout << " massiv dArr iz 5 zna4enij tipa DOUBLE : ";
    cout<< (arrd);
    cout<<"Max znachenie massiva int:"<<max5(arri)<<endl;
    cout<<"Max znachenie massiva double:"<<max5(arrd)<<endl;
    return 0;
```

}

Не могу решить. Ошибки типа:

> cin >> arri[i]; - [Error] invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
>   cin >> arrd[i]; - [Error] invalid types 'double[double]' for array subscript
>   max5(arri) - [Error] no matching function for call to 'max5(int&)'
>   max5(arrd) - [Error] no matching function for call to 'max5(double&)'

Comment: А в чём проблема? Какие у вас вопросы?

Comment: ошибки: cin >> arrd[i]; -[Error] invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript и там еще одна ошибка  max5(arri) - [Error] no matching function for call to 'max5(int&)'

Comment: Это следует добавить к вопросы.

Comment: Судя по всему arrd это не массив, а просто double, тоже кассается arri

Comment: в смысле не массив? А как это исправить?

Comment: Объявить его как массив. Синтаксис можно посмотреть в [справочнике](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array). Кстати в функции `max5(T arr[])` параметр `arr` тоже не является массивом.

Comment: я нашел, где я ошибся. но вылезла новая ошибка:  cin >> arrd[i] - [Error] invalid types 'double [5][double]' for array subscript

Comment: использовать double в цикле - крайне нежелательно.

Comment: по условию задачи второй массив должен быть double. Хотел сделать оба массива динамическими, а не заданными в коде программы

Comment: Ну а что непонятного с новой ошибкой?

Comment: плохо понимаю как решить. То есть, динамический массив Дабл лучше не создавать, я правильно понял? И задать его в коде программы?

Answer (score 2):

int arri = arr_size; это не объявление массива.
нужно вот так int arri[arr_size];

тоже касается и double

Answer (score 1):

1) Массивы в С++ объявляются так:

```
int arr[10];
double array[10];
```

2) Нет смысла использовать в цикле в качестве итератора переменную типа double, уже хотя бы потому что переменная `double` может содержать **дробное** число, а индексирование элементов массива происходит **целочисленными** значениями, начиная с нуля.

Comment: А если через вектор попробовать задать, так можно?

Comment: ...include iostream, vector 
#define MAXSIZE 5
template<typename T>
T max5(std::vector<T> &vec)
{
 T max = vec [0];
 for (int i = 1; i < MAXSIZE; i++) if (vec[i] > max) max = vec[i];
 return max;
}

int main() {
 std::vector<int>vecInt(MAXSIZE);
 vecInt[0] = 7;
 vecInt[1] = 6;
 vecInt[2] = -1;
 vecInt[3] = 8;
 vecInt[4] = 3;
 std::vector<double>vecDouble(MAXSIZE);
 vecDouble[0] = 6.4;
 vecDouble[1] = -3.6;
 vecDouble[2] = 11.7;
 vecDouble[3] = 4.9;
 vecDouble[4] = 3.8;

 std::cout << max5(vecInt) << std::endl;
 std::cout << max5(vecDouble) << std::endl;
 return 0;

Answer (score 0):

Поиск наибольшего элемента массива с использованием указателя на первый элемент массива и отдельной переменной, задающей размер массива:

```
template <typename T> T max1(const T *arr, const std::size_t size)
{
    T maxValue = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i)
        if (arr[i] > maxValue)
            maxValue = arr[i];
    return maxValue;
}
...
const size_t SIZE = 5;
int arr1[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
cout << max1(arr1, SIZE) << endl;
```

С использованием двух указателей — на первый элемент массива, и на элемент, следующий непосредственно за последним:

```
template <typename T> T max2(const T *first, const T *last)
{
    T maxValue = *first;
    ++first;
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        if (*first > maxValue)
            maxValue = *first;
    return maxValue;    
}
...
const size_t SIZE = 5;
double arr2[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
cout << max2(arr2, arr2 + SIZE) << endl;
```

С использованием ссылки на массив:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t size> T max3(const T (&arr)[size])
{
    T maxValue = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i)
        if (arr[i] > maxValue)
            maxValue = arr[i];
    return maxValue;
}
...
const size_t SIZE = 5;
double arr3[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
cout << max3(arr3) << endl;
```

С использованием стандартных контейнеров и итераторов:

```
template <typename T> T max4(T first, T last)
{
    if (first == last)
        return last;

    T maxIt = first;
    ++first;
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        if (*first > *maxIt)
            maxIt = first;
    return maxIt;
}
...
array<int, 5> arr4 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
cout << *max4(arr4.begin(), arr4.end()) << endl;
```

Ну или можно сразу воспользоваться шаблонной функцией `std::max_element()`:

```
vector<double> arr5 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
cout << *max_element(arr5.begin(), arr5.end()) << endl;
```

[Примеры использования](https://ideone.com/z9eInC).

Answer (score 0):

Начнём с того, что компилятор каждую строчку разбирает максимально отдельно от других. И при компиляции

```
    T max5(T arr[])
```

он уже не знает про

```
const int arr_size = 5;
```

. А если Вы дальше передадите в функцию массив только из трёх элементов? Проверить этого нельзя. Но при этом функция в строке

```
for(int i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
```

полагается на то, что их пять. Или внесите размер прямо в декларацию формального параметра, или вычисляйте размер внутри функции:

```
template<typename T> T max5(T arr[])
{
 T Result=arr[0];
 size_t size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])
 size_t i;
 for (i=1; i<arr_size; ++i)
 {
  if (arr[i]>Result)
  {
   Result=arr[i];
  }
 }
 return Result;
}
```

. И привыкайте для размеров любых данных использовать только size_t. За исключением сохраняемых в файле динамических массивов с явными ограничениями, не превышающих возможностей других типов. Если программа будет скомпилирована на машинах с одной разрядностью адреса, а потом одна версия файл запишет, а другая его прочитает, то вот здесь size_t вызовет проблемы, так как он будет различаться. И для индексов тоже только size_t за тем же исключением, но только если будете экономить на привидениях. Иначе будет обидно, когда элементов вдруг неожиданно окажется пара десятков миллиардов, а в типе int останутся те же 32 байта, да он ещё и знаковый, что ещё в два раза сокращает максимальное значение. Наконец, а где в шаблон подставлен конкретный тип?